# can you map a windows login to an sql server authentication user?

Tags: sql, database, security, connection

this is for the purpose of cutting an asp.net web application over from using an sql server authentication connection string to using a windows authentication connection string.

Comment: it's not allowed, you can't mix. So now my question is -- do I have to manually create permissions for the windows login(s) or is there a way to copy them over in one shot?

Answer (score 0):

See [How to: Access SQL Server Using Windows Integrated Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bsz5788z(v=vs.100).aspx).

> If your application runs on a Windows-based intranet, you might be able to use Windows integrated authentication for database access. Integrated security uses the current Windows identity established on the operating system thread to access the SQL Server database. You can then map the Windows identity to a SQL Server database and permissions.
>
> To connect to SQL Server using Windows integrated authentication, you must identify the Windows identity under which your ASP.NET application is running. You must also be sure that the identity has been granted access to the SQL Server database. This topic includes a code example that displays the current Windows identity of the ASP.NET application.

As well as the application of this toward an intranet, you can use it for a public website by setting the Application Pool to run as a custom user that has a Windows logon to the SQL Server.